# How do I edit an discord webhook using pure javascript and html?

Tags: javascript, discord

I don't get the [discord's documentation page](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook).
I want to add an edit button to my website, that when you click it, an textbox appears and another button, the textbox would edit the most recent message and the second button would update it, so basically edit it.

Comment: By editing a webhook, did you mean editing the most recent message sent by the specific webhook?

Comment: yes i just said that